# Trouble running JUnit from Ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

Here's the target I'm using to run my tests:

```
<target name="run-tests" description="run the tests" depends="compilation">
        <junit>
            <sysproperty key="tests.basedir" value="${SPECIAL_PATH}/unit_tests"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${COMPILED_CLASSES}"/>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}/junit-4.8.1.jar"/>
            </classpath>
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${COMPILED_CLASSES}/unit_tests/">
                    <include name="**/Test*.class"/>
                    <exclude name="**/*$*"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

However, every time I try to run this target, all my tests fail with something like:

```
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testpackage.TestMyClass
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

The `SPECIAL_PATH` property points to the source code of the classes. The `COMPILED_CLASSES` property points to the place the `.class` files have been put. And I need the `tests.basedir` property because I use it from my unit tests.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:I also thought I should explain the exclude of the `$`. I'm excluding anonymous classes, because they don't represent TestCases, they're only used from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your claspath has

```
${COMPILED_CLASSES}
```

and your test classes are in

```
${COMPILED_CLASSES}/unit_tests
```

they would need to be in package

```
unit_tests.<whatever the classpath is>
```

traditionally this is why people compile normal sources to target/classes and test sources to target/test-classes

Answer (score 3):

You are telling Junit to execute each test class in `${COMPILED_CLASSES}/unit_tests/` but you are putting just `${COMPILED_CLASSES}` on the classpath. You probably need to change your classpath entry to

```
<pathelement location="${COMPILED_CLASSES}/unit_tests/"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't Java descend automatically in that folder? And if I have 20 packages for tests, I need to add them all in the classpath?

Comment: @Geo For folders, it needs start at the package root.  Currently junit thinks the class should be unit_tests.testpackage.TestMyClass instead of testpackage.TestMyClass

Comment: @Kevin, I tried to run a class by it's own, using the `test` task, and it works. It's using the same classpath as the one posted by me. Any ideas why that could be?

Comment: Might be helpful to post the configuration that works to figure out why the original does not

Comment: Kevin, based on your comment with the `unit_tests.testpackage.TestMyClass` package suggestion, I made it work. When I put only `COMPILED_CLASSES` on the fileset, it worked. If you care to write an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: So you changed your package name to match your Ant configuration?

Comment: No, I only removed the `unit_tests` from the string passed to the `dir` property of fileset. Kevin's comment ( and running a single test with the `test` task ) made me realize the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to compile the UnitTests.  Could you post where you use the javac task?